# FastAPI - render template in index.html - NameError

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, jinja2, fastapi

Good day I am using FastAPI and I want to render the database contents on index.html - however I get the following error:

```
INFO:     127.0.0.1:55139 - "GET /?skip=0&limit=100 HTTP/1.1" 500 Internal Server Error
ERROR:    Exception in ASGI application
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/barnaby/.local/share/virtualenvs/fastapi-example-6xjq_vv2/lib/python3.9/site-packages/uvicorn/protocols/http/h11_impl.py", line 394, in run_asgi
    result = await app(self.scope, self.receive, self.send)
  File "/Users/barnaby/.local/share/virtualenvs/fastapi-example-6xjq_vv2/lib/python3.9/site-packages/uvicorn/middleware/proxy_headers.py", line 45, in __call__
    return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/Users/barnaby/.local/share/virtualenvs/fastapi-example-6xjq_vv2/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fastapi/applications.py", line 190, in __call__
    await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
  File "/Users/barnaby/.local/share/virtualenvs/fastapi-example-6xjq_vv2/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/applications.py", line 111, in __call__
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
  File "/Users/barnaby/.local/share/virtualenvs/fastapi-example-6xjq_vv2/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 181, in __call__
    raise exc from None
  File "/Users/barnaby/.local/share/virtualenvs/fastapi-example-6xjq_vv2/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 159, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
  File "/Users/barnaby/.local/share/virtualenvs/fastapi-example-6xjq_vv2/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/middleware/cors.py", line 78, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/Users/barnaby/.local/share/virtualenvs/fastapi-example-6xjq_vv2/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/exceptions.py", line 82, in __call__
    raise exc from None
  File "/Users/barnaby/.local/share/virtualenvs/fastapi-example-6xjq_vv2/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/exceptions.py", line 71, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, sender)
  File "/Users/barnaby/.local/share/virtualenvs/fastapi-example-6xjq_vv2/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 566, in __call__
    await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
  File "/Users/barnaby/.local/share/virtualenvs/fastapi-example-6xjq_vv2/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 227, in handle
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/Users/barnaby/.local/share/virtualenvs/fastapi-example-6xjq_vv2/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 41, in app
    response = await func(request)
  File "/Users/barnaby/.local/share/virtualenvs/fastapi-example-6xjq_vv2/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 188, in app
    raw_response = await run_endpoint_function(
  File "/Users/barnaby/.local/share/virtualenvs/fastapi-example-6xjq_vv2/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 137, in run_endpoint_function
    return await run_in_threadpool(dependant.call, **values)
  File "/Users/barnaby/.local/share/virtualenvs/fastapi-example-6xjq_vv2/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/concurrency.py", line 34, in run_in_threadpool
    return await loop.run_in_executor(None, func, *args)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.0_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 52, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "./sql_app/main.py", line 51, in read_notes
    "title": title,
NameError: name 'title' is not defined
```

Main.py

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from typing import List, Dict

from fastapi import Depends, FastAPI, HTTPException, Request, Response
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates

from . import crud, models, schemas
from .database import SessionLocal, engine

models.Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)

templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="templates")

app = FastAPI()

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=["*"],
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)

# Dependency
def get_db():
    db = SessionLocal()
    try:
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()


# #original function
# @app.get("/notes", response_model=List[schemas.Note])
# def read_notes(request: Request, skip: int = 0, limit: int = 100, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
#     notes = crud.get_notes(db=db, skip=skip, limit=limit)
#     print(notes)
#     return notes



@app.get("/", response_class=HTMLResponse)
def read_notes(request: Request, skip: int = 0, limit: int = 100, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    notes = crud.get_notes(db=db, skip=skip, limit=limit)
    print(notes)
    return templates.TemplateResponse("index.html",{
        "request": request,
        "id": id,
        "title": title,
        "description": description
    })

@app.post("/notes", response_model=schemas.Note, status_code=201)
def create_note(note: schemas.NoteCreate, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    return crud.create_note(db=db, note=note)




@app.get("/notes/{note_id}", response_model=schemas.Note)
def read_user(note_id: int, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    db_note = crud.get_note(db=db, note_id=note_id)
    if db_note is None:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail="Note not found")
    return db_note

@app.delete("/notes/{note_id}", status_code=204)
async def delete_note(note_id: int, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    return crud.delete_note(db=db, note_id=note_id)


@app.put("/notes/{note_id}", status_code=200)
async def put_note(note_id: int, note: schemas.NoteCreate, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    db_note = schemas.Note(id = note_id, title= note.title, description=note.description)
    crud.update_note(db=db, note=db_note)

@app.patch("/notes/{note_id}", status_code=200)
async def patch_note(note_id: int, note: schemas.NoteCreate, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    print(note_id)
    print(note.title)
    print(note.description)
    db_note = schemas.Note(id = note_id, title= note.title, description=note.description)
    crud.update_note(db=db, note=db_note)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run("main:app", host="127.0.0.1", port=8000)
```

crud.py

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

from . import models, schemas


def get_note(db: Session, note_id: int):
    return db.query(models.Note).filter(models.Note.id == note_id).first()

def delete_note(db: Session, note_id: int):
    db_note = db.query(models.Note).filter(models.Note.id == note_id).first()
    db.delete(db_note)
    db.commit()
    return {}

def get_notes(db: Session, skip: int = 0, limit: int = 100):
    return db.query(models.Note).offset(skip).limit(limit).all()


def create_note(db: Session, note: schemas.NoteCreate):
    db_note = models.Note(title=note.title, description=note.description)
    db.add(db_note)
    db.commit()
    db.refresh(db_note)
    return db_note

def update_note(db: Session, note: schemas.Note):
    db_note = db.query(models.Note).filter(models.Note.id == note.id).first()
    db_note.title = note.title
    db_note.description = note.description
    db.commit()
    db.refresh(db_note)
    return db_note
```

schemas.py

```
class NoteBase(BaseModel):
    title: str
    description: str


class NoteCreate(NoteBase):
    pass

class Note(NoteBase):
    id: int

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
```

models.py

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

from .database import Base

class Note(Base):
    __tablename__ = "notes"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    title = Column(String, nullable=True, default="new")
    description = Column(String, nullable=True, default="new")
```

index.html

```
{% extends 'layout.html' %} {% include 'header.html' %} {% block title %} Home {% endblock %} {% block body %}

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col md-12">
            <div class="jumbotron">
                <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">ID</th>
                        <th scope="col">Title</th>
                        <th scope="col">Description</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        {% for note in notes%}
                        <td>{{notes.id}}</td>
                        <td>{{notes.title}}</td>
                        <td>{{notes.description}}</td>
                        </tr>
                        {% endfor %}
                    <tr>
                </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



{% endblock %}
```

Is my schema/models set up incorrectly?
looking at this end point-- http://127.0.0.1:8000/notes i get the following displayed in index.html. However this is in list format.But somehow I am unable to render it via the HTML template.

```
[   {     "title": "title 3",     "description": "title 3 description",     "id": 3   },   {     "title": "title 1 updated",     "description": "string",     "id": 1   },   {     "title": "Title updated 2",     "description": "description updated2",     "id": 2   },   {     "title": "Note 4",     "description": "Note 4 description",     "id": 4   } ]
```

database.py

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker


SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL = "postgresql://postgres:123456789@localhost/notes"

engine = create_engine (SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL)
SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)

Base = declarative_base()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is a result of an undefined variable `title` on line 51 of `main.py` in the `read_notes` function exactly as your stack trace indicates.

Rewrite your endpoint to do something like the following

```
@app.get("/", response_class=HTMLResponse)
def read_notes(request: Request, skip: int = 0, limit: int = 100, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    notes = crud.get_notes(db=db, skip=skip, limit=limit)
    return templates.TemplateResponse("index.html", {
        "notes": notes,
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

I have changed the code accordingly.

```
@app.get("/", response_class=HTMLResponse)
def read_notes(request: Request, skip: int = 0, limit: int = 100, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    notes = crud.get_notes(db=db, skip=skip, limit=limit)
    return templates.TemplateResponse("index.html", {
        "request": request,
        "notes": notes,
    })
```

Also had to change the for loop in index.html which made the table go bonkers..

```
{% extends 'layout.html' %} {% include 'header.html' %} {% block title %} Home {% endblock %} {% block body %}

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col md-12">
            <div class="jumbotron">
                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>ID</th>
                            <th>Title</th>
                            <th>Description</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {%for note in notes%}
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{note.id}}</td>
                            <td>{{note.title}}</td>
                            <td>{{note.description}}</td>
                        </tr>
                        {%endfor%}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Thank you for assisting. I really appreciate it...